# Trying to set a superclass field in a subclass using validator

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to set a super-class field in a subclass using *validator* as follows:

**Approach 1**

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, root_validator
    
class ClassSuper(BaseModel):
  field1: int = 0

class ClassSub(ClassSuper):
  field2: List[int]

  @validator('field1')
  def validate_field1(cls, v, values):
    return len(values["field2"])

sub = ClassSub(field2=[1, 2, 3])
print(sub.field1)  # It prints 0, but expected it to print 3
```

If I run the code above it prints `0`, but I expected it to print `3` (which is basically `len(field2)`). However, if I use `@root_validator()` instead, I get the expected result.

**Approach 2**

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, root_validator
    
class ClassSuper(BaseModel):
  field1: int = 0

class ClassSub(ClassSuper):
  field2: List[int]

  @root_validator()
  def validate_field1(cls, values):
    values["field1"] = len(values["field2"])
    return values

sub = ClassSub(field2=[1, 2, 3])
print(sub.field1)  # This prints 3, as expected
```

New to using *pydantic* and I am bit puzzled what I am doing wrong with the **Approach 1**. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your **Approach 1** does not work is because by default, validators for a field are *not called*, when the value for that field is not supplied (see [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always)).

Your `validate_field1` is never even called. If you add `always=True` to your `@validator`, the method is called, even if you *don't* provide a value for `field1`.

However, if you try that, you'll see that it will ***still* not work**, but instead throw an error about the key `"field2"` not being present in `values`.

This in turn is due to the fact that validators are called in the order they were *defined*. In this case, `field1` is defined before `field2`, which means that `field2` is not yet validated by the time `validate_field1` is called. And `values` **only contains previously-validated fields** (see [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/)). Thus, at the time `validate_field1` is called, `values` is simply an empty dictionary.

Using the `@root_validator` is the correct approach here because it receives the entire model's data, regardless of whether or not field values were supplied explicitly or by default.

And just as a side note: If you don't need to specify any parameters for it, you can use `@root_validator` without the parantheses.

And as another side note: If you are using Python `3.9+`, you can use the regular `list` class as the type annotation. (See standard [generic alias types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type)) That means `field2: list[int]` without the need for `typing.List`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is such a well explained answer! You have actually covered many questions I had in mind, but had not asked explicitly here. Like the key error ... in fact that is how it all started. The side notes are icing on the cake! THANK YOU a ton!!